# Mostrar mensagens de erro de login no Python com Django

Tags: javascript, html, python, django, autenticação

Estou construindo uma página de login no Python com Django, JavaScript e HTML.
O que eu não estou sabendo como fazer é mostrar, na tela de login um alert com as mensagens "Usuário não autorizado" e "Usuário ou senha incorretos".
Minha dúvida especificamente é: como eu faço para enviar a mensagem de erro do arquivo views.py para o login.html, capturando o conteúdo dessa mensagem e mostrando isso dentro de um alert.
Abaixo meu código:

**login.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="app-title">
            <h2>Entre no Sistema</h2>
        </div>

        <form class="login-form" method=POST>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" name=username placeholder="usuário">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" name=password placeholder="senha">
            </div>

            <input type=submit class="btn" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import ldap, json, os


def login(request):
    usuarios = ler_usuarios_cadastrados()

    request.session['username'] = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username == 'admin' and password == 'admin':
            request.session['username'] = username
            request.session['campus'] = 0
            request.session['curso'] = 0
            return redirect('/geral')
        else:
            if username not in usuarios:
                #aqui deve mostrar a mensagem "Usuário não autorizado"
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                request.session['username'] = username
                request.session['campus'] = usuarios[username]['campus_id']
                request.session['curso'] = usuarios[username]['curso_id']

            username_ldap = 'uid=' + username + ',ou=People,dc=xpto,dc=abacaxi,dc=edu,dc=br'
            try:
                conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.xpto.abacaxi.edu.br')
                conn.protocol_version = 3
                conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
                conn.simple_bind_s(username_ldap, password)
            except ldap.LDAPError:
                #aqui deve mostrar a mensagem "Usuário ou senha incorretos"
                return redirect('login')
            return redirect('/geral')
    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')

def ler_usuarios_cadastrados():
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'usuarios_cadastrados.json')
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf8") as usuarios_cadastrados: 
        return json.load(usuarios_cadastrados)
```

OBS: toda a lógica do login está funcionando corretamente. Apenas gostaria de incluir as mensagens de erro.
Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o sistema de mensagens do próprio Django, você poderá ver todas as opções clicando [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/).

Para enviar uma mensagem de falha no login, por exemplo, você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def login(request):
    usuarios = ler_usuarios_cadastrados()

    request.session['username'] = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username == 'admin' and password == 'admin':
            request.session['username'] = username
            request.session['campus'] = 0
            request.session['curso'] = 0
            return redirect('/geral')
        else:
            if username not in usuarios:
                # Aqui é onde a magia acontece
                messages.info(request, 'Usuário não autorizado')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                request.session['username'] = username
                request.session['campus'] = usuarios[username]['campus_id']
                request.session['curso'] = usuarios[username]['curso_id']

            username_ldap = 'uid=' + username + ',ou=People,dc=xpto,dc=abacaxi,dc=edu,dc=br'
            try:
                conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.xpto.abacaxi.edu.br')
                conn.protocol_version = 3
                conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
                conn.simple_bind_s(username_ldap, password)
            except ldap.LDAPError:
                #aqui deve mostrar a mensagem "Usuário ou senha incorretos"
                return redirect('login')
            return redirect('/geral')
    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')
```

Para exibir a mensagem em seu template, basta adicionar o seguinte no template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for m in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
          {{ m }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Espero que isso seja útil.

Comment: obrigado graças a sua resposta resolvi meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Viva crias um template para os erros, e fazes include nos templates que queiras mostrar erros. Agora não sei porque estás a ler os users de um ficheiro de txt, quando utilizando db é mais simples.

**errors.html**

```
{% if item.total_error_count %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger col-12 mx-1" role="alert">
        <div id="form_errors">
            {% if item.non_form_errors %}
                {{ item.non_form_errors }}
            {% endif %}
            {% for error in item.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**login.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="app-title">
            <h2>Entre no Sistema</h2>
        </div>

        <form class="login-form" method=POST>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" name=username placeholder="usuário">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" name=password placeholder="senha">
            </div>
            {% include 'errors.html' %} <!-- Coloca aqui o include do template, mas coloca o path correto-->
            <input type=submit class="btn" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django import forms

...
           if username not in usuarios:
                # este mecanismo é tipico a sua utilização no forms, não sei se vai funcionar diretamente aqui, mas com o import do forms, o return seguinte será inutil.
                raise forms.ValidationError('Não existe o utilizador.'))
                #aqui deve mostrar a mensagem "Usuário não autorizado"
                return redirect('login')
...
```

NOTA: A melhor abordagem seria, mudares para db e adicionares forms e o login era mais simples. Código abaixo.

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    """Login form for users."""
    username = forms.CharField(required = True, label = _('Username'), max_length = 32,)
    password = forms.CharField(required = True, label = _('Palavra Passe'), max_length = 32, widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    remember_user = forms.BooleanField(required = False, label = 'Memorizar')
    
    def clean(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact = self.cleaned_data['usernam'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username ou Palavra passe inválida, corriga por favor.')
        
        if not user.check_password(self.cleaned_data['password']):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username ou Palavra passe inválida, corriga por favor.')
        
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    """Display and processs the login form."""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = auth.authenticate(username = form.cleaned_data['username'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user:
                redirect('/geral')
            else:
                redirect('login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    render(request,'login.html')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas como sou iniciante a resposta do @VictorFernandes fez mais sentido pra mim por ser mais simples. Aproveitando, eu estou lendo os usuários de um arquivo pq no momento não tenho acesso ao banco de dados.

Comment: Claro que sim, se resolveres utilizar base de dados. Tens aqui a solução. Boa aprendizagem.